# XSLT : How to split strings of text into phrases or words

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, split

I appologize in advance, my knowledge if xsl transformations is poor.

I have created a xml document with paragraphs of text. These paragraphs contain other elements like `<em>`, `<title>`, `<pb>`...

for example :

```
<document>
<body xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" epub:type="bodymatter">
<chap>
<tit>Une adorable petite dévoreuse de livres</tit>
<p>A <em>trois ans</em>, Matilda avait appris toute seule à lire en s'exerçant avec les journaux et les magazines qui traî<pb ed="original" n="14">14</pb>naient à la maison. A quatre ans, elle lisait couramment et, tout naturellement, se mit à rêver de livres. Le seul disponible dans ce foyer de haute culture, <title type="oeuvre">La Cuisine pour tous</title>, appartenait à sa mère et, lorsqu'elle l'eut épluché de la première page à la dernière et appris toutes les recettes par cœur, elle décida de se lancer dans des lectures plus intéressantes. </p>
</chap>
</document>
```

I need to split my text into sentences, adding an element `<span class="sentence">` around them.
And then I need, for each sentence, to add an element `<span class="word">` around each word, taking ito account the other elements already there.

so I need to obtain something like :

```
<p><span class="sentence">A <em>trois ans</em>, Matilda avait appris toute seule à lire en s'exerçant avec les journaux et les magazines qui traî<pb ed="original" n="14">14</pb>naient à la maison.</span> ...</p>
```

and then :

```
<p><span class="sentence"><span class="word">A</span> <em><span class="word">trois</span> <span class="word">ans</span></em>, <span class="word">Matilda</span> <span class="word">avait</span> <span class="word">appris</span> <span class="word">toute</span> <span class="word">seule</span> <span class="word">à</span> <span class="word">lire</span> <span class="word">en</span> <span class="word">s'exerçant</span> <span class="word">avec</span> <span class="word">les</span> <span class="word">journaux</span> <span class="word">et</span> <span class="word">les</span> <span class="word">magazines</span> <span class="word">qui</span> <span class="word">traî<pb ed="original" n="14">14</pb>naient</span> <span class="word">à</span> <span class="word">la</span> <span class="word">maison</span>.</span> ...</p>
```

As you can see, sometimes I need the elements to be inside other elements (inside the `<em>` because there are multiple words inside) and other times I don't take elements into account (`<pb ed="original" n="14">14</pb>` won't appear, it's only there to refer to the location of the pages on the printed version)

Is this kind of splitting possible ?

I thank you for any help you could offer me.

Comment: Regular expressions are supported in XSLT through extension functions and in XSLT 2 and later by functions like `tokenize`, `matches` and the `xsl:analyze-string` instruction plus in XSLT 3 by the `analyze-string` function. All these operate on plain strings so with mixed contents you will need separate processing steps. Furthermore what constitutes a sentence or a word is language and culture dependent and at least in the pure regular expression support of the XSLT/XPath standard there are no provisions for word boundaries. So you could only tokenize or match on white-space between words.

Comment: I also wonder whether part of the sample data like `s'exerçant` would match as a single word in any regular expression dialect using e.g. `\w` or `\b`. But I don't know all platform specific details.

Comment: Note also that if a markup such as `em` spans a sentence (or a word) boundary, the task becomes impossible - at least as currently defined.

Comment: @MartinHonnen and @michael.hor257k Thank you both for your replies. I think I will need to add the `<span class="sentence">` on my own if as you say these functions only work on plain strings. Then I will try the functions you mentioned to insert the `<span class="word">` on different levels where they are needed.                                                                    I think splitting the text depending on spaces to separate the words will be less complex as you mentioned than cases with punctuation inside the texte (I'll need to be careful of the last words of a sentence though).

Comment: It is possible to identify characters like a dot that mark the end of a sentence, mark it up as an element (e.g. `<eos>.</eos>`), then in a second step use grouping like `for-each-group select="node()" group-ending-with="eos"` to wrap each group as wanted. In a further step you can wrap words.  And any effort depends on how complicated/nested your structure is, if the sentence ending characters like a dot are always in a text child of a `p` the grouping is easy, if they are further down the hierarchy it is more effort although there are existing papers and libraries doing that.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I tried to insert these elements `<eos></eos>` but  I realized I had the same problem to find the punctuation signs as when I'm looking for sentences to add `<span class="sentence">`. I will try to work on it in the coming days thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to first wrap sentences and then to wrap anything not being whitespace as a word, using XSLT 3:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:param name="sentence-markers" as="xs:string" select="'[!?\.]'"/>

  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:variable name="mark-sentence-ends">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="sentence"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <p>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="$mark-sentence-ends/node()" group-ending-with="eos">
        <span class="sentence">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="wrap-words"/>
        </span>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:mode name="wrap-words" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template mode="wrap-words" match="text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\s+">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <span class="word">{.}</span>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template mode="wrap-words" match="pb"/>
  
  <xsl:template mode="wrap-words" match="title">
    <span class="{@type}">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
    </span>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template mode="wrap-words" match="eos">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:mode name="sentence" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template mode="sentence" match="text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{$sentence-markers}">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <eos>{.}</eos>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="document">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Example</title>
      </head>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="body">
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="tit">
    <h1>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </h1>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="chap">
    <section>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </section>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you this works even with the ' sign. I changed the regex for the words to `regex="[\s-]+"` because I also have `<u>` elements that I didn't mention and they start the dialogues lines with a sign -. There is still a confusion with "M." (Mr.) that is considered as a sentence because of the point. It appears as : `<span class="sentence"><span class="word">M</span>.</span>`

Comment: Also, what's really interesting is that sometimes I have a paragraph that ends with the sign " : " `<p>text :</p>` and this text is correctly surrounded by a `<span>` for the sentence. While the signs : in the middle of a sentence are not taken into account that way. If it's not too much to ask could you tell me what line of your code does that ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you could posssibly use as your starting point. It uses the `\w` "word character" character class to split the text into individual words (as mentioned in comments, XSLT's regex has no support for the `\b` word boundary anchor).

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p//text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\w+">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <span class="word">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </span>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given your example (after correcting it for well-formedness!), this will replace the `p` element with:

```
<p><span class="word">A</span> <em><span class="word">trois</span> <span class="word">ans</span></em>, <span class="word">Matilda</span> <span class="word">avait</span> <span class="word">appris</span> <span class="word">toute</span> <span class="word">seule</span> <span class="word">à</span> <span class="word">lire</span> <span class="word">en</span> <span class="word">s</span>'<span class="word">exerçant</span> <span class="word">avec</span> <span class="word">les</span> <span class="word">journaux</span> <span class="word">et</span> <span class="word">les</span> <span class="word">magazines</span> <span class="word">qui</span> <span class="word">traî</span><pb ed="original" n="14"><span class="word">14</span></pb><span class="word">naient</span> <span class="word">à</span> <span class="word">la</span> <span class="word">maison</span>. <span class="word">A</span> <span class="word">quatre</span> <span class="word">ans</span>, <span class="word">elle</span> <span class="word">lisait</span> <span class="word">couramment</span> <span class="word">et</span>, <span class="word">tout</span> <span class="word">naturellement</span>, <span class="word">se</span> <span class="word">mit</span> <span class="word">à</span> <span class="word">rêver</span> <span class="word">de</span> <span class="word">livres</span>. <span class="word">Le</span> <span class="word">seul</span> <span class="word">disponible</span> <span class="word">dans</span> <span class="word">ce</span> <span class="word">foyer</span> <span class="word">de</span> <span class="word">haute</span> <span class="word">culture</span>, <title type="oeuvre"><span class="word">La</span> <span class="word">Cuisine</span> <span class="word">pour</span> <span class="word">tous</span></title>, <span class="word">appartenait</span> <span class="word">à</span> <span class="word">sa</span> <span class="word">mère</span> <span class="word">et</span>, <span class="word">lorsqu</span>'<span class="word">elle</span> <span class="word">l</span>'<span class="word">eut</span> <span class="word">épluché</span> <span class="word">de</span> <span class="word">la</span> <span class="word">première</span> <span class="word">page</span> <span class="word">à</span> <span class="word">la</span> <span class="word">dernière</span> <span class="word">et</span> <span class="word">appris</span> <span class="word">toutes</span> <span class="word">les</span> <span class="word">recettes</span> <span class="word">par</span> <span class="word">cœur</span>, <span class="word">elle</span> <span class="word">décida</span> <span class="word">de</span> <span class="word">se</span> <span class="word">lancer</span> <span class="word">dans</span> <span class="word">des</span> <span class="word">lectures</span> <span class="word">plus</span> <span class="word">intéressantes</span>. </p>
```

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93wniUm
*(Change the indent to "yes" to better observe the splitting action.)*

---

If this provides a satisfactory output, you could move to the next step of creating the sentence wrappers. However, I suspect that you will need a human eye to go over the result and make corrections where necessary, and - as I already mentioned in the comments - you may have to put in a lot more work if a sentence or a word boundary can be within another element.

---

***--- added ---***

To prevent an apostrophe from breaking up a word, try:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="string" regex="[\w']+">
```

Comment: Thank you. It works exept for words with ' inside. For example "C'était" appears as `<span class="word">C</span>'<span class="word">était</span>`  I tried to change the regex but the sign ' doesn't seem to be recognizable. I tried the regex regex="\w+'?w+" to say that I want letters followed by the sign 0 times or once and then followed by other letters. It doesn't work. I also tried regex="\w+\'?w+" because I know that the backslash cancels signs already used in the language for something else but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @AudreyCostes See if the addition to my answer helps.

Comment: Yes it wokrs perfectly thank you, even with words like "Aujourd'hui" (today). I see, so I needed to put the repetition of the expression outside. I didn't think of this.